# A continuously differentiable operator has no isolated points

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations

Suppose we have a invertible linear operator that is continuously differentiable. Does that imply that it has no isolated points? If not, can I get an examle to disprove this statement. 
So what exactly do one need to show to prove some function has no isolated points?

Comment: What is the defintion of an isolated point?